# make specific icon marker depend on category from json in android google map

Tags: android, json, google-maps

i have a problem, i want to make icon marker different each category, i have 3 category 1.pendidikan , 2. pariwisata 3. industri , and i want to make for pendidikan (icon hue_blue), pariwisata (hue_yellow) and industri (hue_green)

this is source code i have
SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
       peta = mapFrag.getMap();

```
   peta.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
   moveToMyLocation();


   for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.size(); i++)

   {

       HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

       map = dataArray.get(i);

       LatLng tampilkanpetanya = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(map.get(tag_latitude)),Double.parseDouble(map.get(tag_longitude)));
       markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
       markerOptions.position(tampilkanpetanya);
       markerOptions.title(map.get("lokasi_id"));
       markerOptions.snippet(map.get("nama_lokasi"));
       //markerOptions.getAttribute(map.get("lokasi_id"));
       markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
       cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(tampilkanpetanya).zoom(12).build();
       peta.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
       peta.addMarker(markerOptions);
       peta.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID)
```

Comment: You can create 3 different MarkerOptions with different colors outside your for loop and use the correct one in peta.addMarker() depending on the category.

Comment: but if i move marker option to outside the loop, how i get LatLng tampilkanpetanya , because it must get array(i)

Comment: You would need to store the category of each location in your Hashmap.  final int PENDIDIKAN = 0; int category = map.get("category");  if(category == 0) { peta.addMarker(markerOptionsPendidikan); }

Comment: and i want show the marker all category in one map with 3 colour depend on category, not select one category

Comment: can you make the source code correct for me? please i so confuse

Comment: Your source code is fine but you have an issue with your data structure.  You can use the code from Kaschwenk's answer in your for loop but you need to modify your hash map to store the category of each location.

Comment: HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(tag_kategori_id, kategori_id); in outside for loop and inside loop if(tag_kategori_id.equals("1")) {
      markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
  } else if(tag_kategori_id.equals("2")) {
       markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));
  } else {
      // Defaultcase
       markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
 }

Comment: Yes, that looks like it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this (assuming your category is a string):

```
String category = ....getCategory();
if(category.equals("pariwisata")) {
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
} else if(category.equals("pariwisata")) {
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));
} else {
    // Defaultcase
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
}
```

Comment: String category = map.get("category") did you mean?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how you get the category in your app. So call Whatever method you need to call to get the category the icon marker should represent.

Comment: i get from json : try{
        
        distro = json.getJSONArray("data");
        for(int i = 0; i < distro.length(); i++){
         JSONObject data = distro.getJSONObject(i);
         
         if(data == null){
          
         }
         else {
          id = data.getString(tag_id);
          kategori_id = data.getString(tag_kategori_id);
          subkategori_id = data.getString(tag_subkategori_id);

   HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
          
          map.put(tag_kategori_id, kategori_id);
          map.put(tag_subkategori_id, subkategori_id);

Comment: plz accept my answer if it works (at least that is the impression that I've got after reading the comments in your original question).